# Realm & CocoaPods conflicting

Tags: ruby, xcode, rvm, cocoapods, realm

Prerequisites :

- Problems arose after duplicating and renaming project
- Tried to fix it without updating anything
- pod 'Realm', '0.97.0'
- pod --version 0.39.0
- Xcode Version 7.3.1 (7D1014)
- Deleted /Xcode/DerivedData/
- Deleted /Library/Caches/CocoaPods
- Deleted pod.lock
- Deleted /Pods/*
- Deleted .xcworkspace
- Opened up the new .xcworkspace
- Product > Clean

Results in 'Realm/Realm.h' file not found

https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1918 Adding Pods/** in the Build Settings > Header Search Paths (seemed to fix it but it's not a proper fix)

Some other issues I've encountered:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3886
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4391
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4754

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1, 2 & 3 only apply when you recently renamed your project:

1. Reset the .xcodeproj file from the previous project and follow [these steps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/RenamingaProject/RenamingaProject.html)
2. Re-created all schemes in Manage Schemes...
3. Build Phases > Compile Sources > Delete everything > Readd all your implementation files.
4. Downgrade Ruby to 2.4, because of next step (ruby on OSX ElCapitain - don't forget that RVM creates a new completely separate gem directory for each version of ruby)
5. Downgrade CocoaPods to 0.38.0, because of realm specific errors.
6. Clean install of Realm (latest version 1.0.1)

Plus all the steps I mentioned in the initial question

Please let me know if there is a way to use the latest version of CocoaPods (1.0.1+) and Realm (1.0.1) without having issues.